# Laravel Active Validation Rule

Tags: laravel, validation

I am extremely new to Laravel and I was wondering if you could help me create a Custom Validation Rule, I am using version 5.5 of Laravel.

What I try to do is the following, I understand that the validations can be defined in the following way:

```
'email' => 'required|string'
```

I would like to add a new rule, in specific one called `'active'`

In the application that I want to create I have several tables in which there are columns called `'active'` (boolean) .. example

Users:

```
id|name|email|active
```

Roles:

```
id|name|active
```

I need a rule that I can call as follows:

```
'email' => 'required|string|active'
```

In short, I need a rule that verifies in a specific table, if the value I'm validating is active, and if not, send me a message. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I've said this recently, but validation is for handling input from client to server; it's not for validating the record in the Database. That can be done by `if($recordFromDB->active){ ... })` after the validation has passed.

Comment: See the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: so, `exists` rule

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Rule class and 'exists' validation:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'email' => [
        'required',
        'string',
         Rule::exists('your_table')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('active', 1);
        }),
    ]
```

Comment: humm... but, how to make that rule accessible in the future for other validations, I mean, there must be some way of declaring that rule as if it were a function or something, where you only have to declare at the time of validation `'require|string|active'` and how to define the error message in case this validation is not fulfilled?

Comment: You could try to using custom validation. Exist many ways to declare Custom Validation.. so you can try call the rule inside them.... Take a look:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules

To define the error message for this rule simple use 'email.exists' => '...';

ps: my english is rusty.

Comment: Inside a custom validation o can call all the models and make the necessary queries....